# VBA Refactoring, MsgBox everywhere

Tags: vba, excel, refactoring

I'm very reluctant to post this as I'm not looking for anyone to write code, rather to get me moving in the right direction here.

I have inherited a huge mass of VBA. I've rewritten an awful lot of it, but I've hit a wall here.

Basically the code checks through millions of lines of an external file, and checks character by character for certain values. However, the code displays a message box `MsgBox` for EVERY single value.

Here is an example:

```
If CharArray(1) = "S" & CharArray(2) = "SO" Then
    MsgBox "Hello Stack Overflow"
    Else: MsgBox "Hello somewhere else"
EndIf
```

And it goes on like this, thousands of times. I will refactor the endless If statements myself. Is there anything I can do to save this? I was going to just comment out manually any MsgBox that isn't displaying an error, but it's still potentially a mess.

Can I write to a cell with the data, and increment to the next row easily from my own Sub or Function to just do a replace of MsgBox with something else? That is to say write Sub ReplaceMsgBoxes() have it write to a current row, whatever the message box was going to write, and go on a line?

Questions:

Would this Sub need a global counter variable (for the Row to write to)? 
Is there a commonly used method by programmers to get around this kind of mess? 
If I write a Sub to replace this can I call the same way, i.e.

```
ReplaceMsgBox "Whatever the text for the MsgBox was to begin with"
```

Many thanks.

Comment: if the code is of the above format then you can do a Replace by pressing CTRL + H and replace `Msgbox` with `'MsgBox`?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout that's what I was thinking of doing yep, was just wondering if I could save what's there since the information from the MsgBox is acutally useful, just not the MsgBox itself! I'm going to do that if I can't work around it.

Comment: Replace it with `Debug.Print`?

Comment: Or do you want to output it to a sheet? Replace 

`MsgBox`

with

`Sheet1.Range("A" & (Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)).Value =`

Replace `Sheet1` with the relevant sheet. This will out the data to a new row everytime.

Comment: If you're really lazy you could just write your own routine called `MsgBox` and have it write to the next available cell as @SiddharthRout demonstrated. Anywhere you need to use the regular messages, use `VBA.Msgbox` :)

Comment: Hi guys, both are good, and I'll run with that, thanks for the comments. :) Great ideas from everyone. I'd kiss you if Stack Overflow hadn't made me sign that form saying I wouldn't!

Comment: @Rory "If you're really lazy" - Yes, yes I am!

Comment: @SiddharthRout `Sheet1.Range("A" & (Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)).Value =` is the way I decided to go. It took about 1 second to change them all, and no issues. It's great, thanks a million again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to buffer the material into a string and then do a single **MsgBox**
Say we want to find all the *dog* in **A1** thru **A100**

```
Sub FindDog()
    Dim dog As String, msg As String
    dog = "dog"
    msg = ""
    For i = 1 To 100
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = dog Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

If there were very many items, I would use a scrollable ListBox instead.

Comment: Scrollable ListBox... Didn't think of that at all! Thanks, that's a great idea, and your solution looks workable from here, many thanks I appreciate it!

Comment: There's another MsgBox in this, they are multiplying like Tribbles! I'm going to buffer it into cells I think, the values being read are from an external text, I need to parse char by char (already working) and display it to myself in some manner I can understand. I'll run form here.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a cell:

```
activecell = "what ever you want to say"
```

to advance to the next cell (below)

```
activecell.offset(1,0).select
```

Comment: You are making matters more worse for him :D